# How to magnify dock icons on mouse hover in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without changing the theme?

Tags: mouse, icons, dock

I have a MacOS theme on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now is there any way to make the dock icons magnify automatically why we hover mouse pointer over them? It will be a beautiful feature to have. Can we do it in any way without changing the existing theme? This feature is also desired in app section where icons automatically magnify themselves as we move the mouse pointer over them.
Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu uses Gnome Shell as its desktop environment. The dock is created by a Gnome Shell extension, "Ubuntu Dock", which is derived of "Dash to Dock". Neither Gnome Shell nor the extensions support the visual effect of enlarging icons, so as such, the answer is "no". The feature is also not available in the app section.

With respect to the dock, there is a way to achieve what you want by using an alternative dock. One such dock is Plank. You could disable the build-in dock, and then have Plank autostart instead. Plank can be configured to have the effect you want, and can be placed on any side of the screen.

To install Plank, enter the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt install plank
```

To edit Plank settings, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and right click on Plank, or open the preferences dialog with the command:

```
plank --preferences
```

You will find the option "Icon zoom" on the tab "Appearance" in the "Preferences dialog. With the slider on the right, you can control the extent of icon zoom.
[image: Plank Preferences Dialog]

Comment: I have succeeded in creating plank, configuring it and adding apps to it. I have to more questions regarding plank but I do not know if they have been answered somewhere or not. 1. Can we add superkey in plank? 2. Can we create app folders in plank? (This I ask because we can associate similar apps together!! Excellent feature this would be.) Please guide me. Thanks. :)