# How can we auto-magnify/enlarge icons inside the app section on mouse hover in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? (Thank you.)

Tags: unity

[image]

This feature is available in plank.
But is there any gnome extension or possibility to auto enlarge/magnify these icons inside the app section on mouse hover? This will be a beautiful feature if there is one. If anyone knows how this can be done, I request them to post a way. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: isn't this your third time of asking the same question?

Comment: No when did I ask this previousl? If that is the case, I will remove my previous question or this one, whichever is less describing the issue. I will also make a search in my own questions to see if this is true. :) Edit: I checked my question list and no I have not asked this question previously. Previous question was related to dock and plank. :) This one relates to inside the app section icons. I have attached a picture to be clear on this. Thanks. :)

Comment: [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306368/inside-the-app-section-is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-the-icons-in-ubuntu)- [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305707/how-to-magnify-dock-icons-on-mouse-hover-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-without-changing-th) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306381/how-can-we-auto-magnify-enlarge-icons-inside-the-app-section-on-mouse-hover-in-u)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306368/inside-the-app-section-is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-the-icons-in-ubuntu             This is related to size enlargement not auto magnification on mouse hover.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305707/how-to-magnify-dock-icons-on-mouse-hover-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-without-changing-th              This one relates to dock icons. Query is resolved now. Installing plank was the answer.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306381/how-can-we-auto-magnify-enlarge-icons-inside-the-app-section-on-mouse-hover-in-u This is my current question. Are you reading the questions properly?

Comment: I am very sorry, I just realise my comment expresses rudeness. But it is also fact that all three questions are different. If I post all three questions in same question then users in past have pointed that one must ask one question at a time at Ask Ubuntu. So I posted them all separately. However all are different questions, because the section they apply to are different.Thank you. :)